# Como pasar multiples arreglos de una función a otra

Tags: javascript, jquery

En la primera función (sectionAturas()) obtuve tres arreglos (secsTops, secsMiddle, secsBottom) que necesito pasar a la segunda función (activeScroll).

Inicialmente declare tres variables globales para recibir sus valores una ves terminada la primera función. (reciboTops, reciboMiddles, reciboBottoms). Sin embargo no logro recibir sus valores en la siguiente función al llamar las variables.

Alguna sugerencia? Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
  var reciboTops = new Array();
  var reciboBottoms = new Array();
  var reciboMiddles = new Array();

 function SectionAlturas(){

    var altWin = $(window).height();
    console.log("Altura Pantalla: " + altWin);
    var altDoc = $(document).height();
    console.log("Altura Documento: " + altDoc);
    var secciones = $(document).find('.section1');
    var suma = 0;
    var secsMiddle = new Array();
    var secsBottom = new Array();
    var secsTops = new Array();
    var setent = ["home", "quienessomos", "comofunciona", "negocio", "cobertura", "urge", "contacto"];

    for (var i = 0; i <= secciones.length; i++) {
        var altCurrSec = $('.section1').eq(i).height();
        if(i == 0){
            secsTops[i] = 0;
            secsBottom[i] = altCurrSec;
            secsMiddle[i] = altCurrSec/2; 
            console.log(setent[i] + " top: " + secsTops[i] + " bottom: " + secsBottom[i]);
        console.log(altCurrSec);
        } else if (i > 0 && i <= secciones.length - 1){
            suma = altCurrSec + secsBottom[i - 1];
            secsTops[i] = secsBottom[i - 1];
            secsBottom[i] = suma;
            secsMiddle[i] = secsBottom[i] - secsTops[i];
            console.log(setent[i] + " top: " + secsTops[i] + " bottom: " + secsBottom[i]);
        console.log(altCurrSec);
        }
    };

    reciboTops = secsTops;
    reciboBottoms = secsBottom;
    reciboMiddles = secsMiddle;


}

function activeScroll(){
    var secciones = $(document).find('.section1');
    var altWin = $(window).height();
    var altDoc =  $(document).height();
    var docCurrTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var indicador = docCurrTop - (altWin/2 - 35);
    var top = new Array();
    var middle = new Array();
    var bottom = new Array();


    for (i = 0; i < secciones.length; i++) {
        console.log("entre al for");

        // var altCurrSec=  $('.section1').eq(i).height();
        top = reciboTops;
        console.log(top);
        middle = reciboMiddles;
        bottom = reciboBottoms;

        // alert(top + ' ' + middle + ' ' + bottom);
        if(indicador >= top[i] && indicador <= bottom[i]){
            console.log("entre 1")
            //caso home
            if (i == 1 && docCurrTop == 0 || i == 1 && indicador == middle[i]){
                console.log("si entra 2");
                $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active1");
                var soy = $('.section1').eq(i).attr("id");
                $('.navli[target="' + soy + '"]').addClass("active1");
            } else if(i == 3 && docCurrTop == top[i] || i == 3 && indicador == bottom[i]){
                console.log("si entra 3");
                $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active1");
                var soy = $('.section1').eq(i).attr("id");
                $('.navli[target="' + soy + '"]').addClass("active1");
            } else if ((i == 2 || i > 3 && i < 7) && (indicador == middle[i])){
                console.log("si entra 4");
                $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active1");
                var soy = $('.section1').eq(i).attr("id");
                $('.navli[target="' + soy + '"]').addClass("active1");
            } else if(i == 7 && docCurrTop == (altDoc - altWin) || i == 7 && indicador <= top[i]){
                console.log("si entra 5");
                $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active1");
                var soy = $('.section1').eq(i).attr("id");
                $('.navli[target="' + soy + '"]').addClass("active1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrias añadir la salida de tu programa, para entender mejor el error que tienes?

Comment: mucho codigo, puedes mejorar tu pregunta citando un codigo minimo, completo y verificable por favor, ademas que no entiendo a que variables te refieres

Answer (score 0):

Sin considerar que hace el resto del código, si necesitas retornar una estructura compleja como esta (3 arreglos) definitivamente tienes que usar un objeto para hacerlo, por una cuestión de comodidad.

Te dejo un ejemplo que mueve multiples arreglos de una función a otra, sin  variables globales y Comentado paso a paso.

Salu2

```js
function produceDatos(cantidad) {
  // hay que crear el objeto:
  var resultado = {};

  // luego le cargamos datos
  resultado.cantidad = cantidad;
  resultado.unArreglo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  resultado.otroArreglo = new Array();

  // agregamos mas datos al arreglo
  resultado.otroArreglo.push(5);
  resultado.otroArreglo.push(6);

  // y otras cosas ... 

  // retornamos el objeto
  return resultado;
}

function consumeObjeto(entrada) {
  // imprimimos algunos datos
  console.log("cantidad:", entrada.cantidad);

  // procesamos todos los elementos de algun arreglo 
  entrada.otroArreglo.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  });

  // hacemo algo con el otro arreglo
  console.log(entrada.unArreglo);
}

/// Aqui los usamos

var datosAqui = produceDatos(5);

consumeObjeto(datosAqui);
```